# How to test component before useEffect with @testing-library/react?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I can do it only with `react-test-renderer`

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(1);
  }, []);

  return <>{count}</>;
}

describe('react-test-renderer', () => {
  const renderer = create(<Counter />);

  it('renders 0', () => {
    expect(renderer.root.children).toContain('0');
  });

  it('renders 1', () => {
    renderer.update(<Counter />);
    expect(renderer.root.children).toContain('1');
  });
});

describe('@testing-library/react', () => {
  const screen = render(<Counter />);

  it('renders 0', () => {
    expect(screen.container).toHaveTextContent('0'); // Not Working!
  });

  it('renders 1', () => {
    screen.rerender(<Counter />);
    expect(screen.container).toHaveTextContent('1');
  });
});
```

[On Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-morning-vcbug?file=/src/__tests__/index.js:700-784)